# $.ajax working, but $.post fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the short hand version of posting data. My old way worked. I'm not understanding why the new way is not working.

On my controller, all the values are NULL. But in the old working version, they parsed fine.

Working:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'api/User/Register',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                EmailAddress: self.RegisterEmailAddress(),
                Password: self.RegisterPassword(),
                TimeZoneID: self.RegisterTimeZoneID(),
                Firstname: self.RegisterFirstname(),
                Surname: self.RegisterSurname()
            }),
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

Not working:

```
var registerdata = JSON.stringify({
    EmailAddress: self.RegisterEmailAddress(),
    Password: self.RegisterPassword(),
    TimeZoneID: self.RegisterTimeZoneID(),
    Firstname: self.RegisterFirstname(),
    Surname: self.RegisterSurname()
});

var uri = 'api/User/Register';

$.post(uri, registerdata)
    .done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

What is incorrect with the new version?
Note, as I post, the header has the correct data:

```
{"EmailAddress":"me@here.com","Password":"password","TimeZoneID":"4","Firstname":"Test","Surname":"Users"}:
```

On my controller the api looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Register(UserRegistrationRequestDto register)
{
    var reply = _userService.Register(register);
    return $"{reply.FriendlyMessage}";
}
```

And the UserRegistrationRequestDto is defined as:

```
 public class UserRegistrationRequestDto : BaseRequestDto
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int TimeZoneID { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't see why the short version isn't working.

Note, a different call worked 100%

```
 var logindata = JSON.stringify({
            EmailAddress: self.LoginEmailAddress(),
            Password: self.LoginPassword()
        });

        var uri = 'api/User/Login'

        $.post(uri, logindata)
            .done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
```

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: Have you checked the error you get back for the reason why it doesn't work? The only difference I can see is the contentType header

Comment: "What is incorrect with the new version?" you're missing contentType and dataType

Comment: All the values are NULL when the api is called. So, "register" arrives at the controller, but all fields are NULL.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev and Rory - I just added a different call to the same controller, except, it's the login call, and it worked 100% without contentType.

Comment: That's interesting. Something must be different here.

Comment: @JimStewart - this could be the issue. I have done the same call method on a different method, and it worked though.

Comment: Check request headers for both call, is there any difference?

Comment: I actually deleted my comment because I thought it was wrong; glad you saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass settings to `.post` like this:

```
$.post({url: uri, contentType: "application/json", data: registerdata});
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I'm not sure why though, because my login one (as posted) worked without the contentType. But this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try Like This.

```
var registerdata = {
            EmailAddress: self.RegisterEmailAddress(),
            Password: self.RegisterPassword(),
            TimeZoneID: self.RegisterTimeZoneID(),
            Firstname: self.RegisterFirstname(),
            Surname: self.RegisterSurname()
        };
var uri = 'api/User/Register';

$.post(uri, registerdata,
     function(response){
        alert(response);
      },"JSON");
```